# Why do we need two constraints to calculate the friction impulse?

Tags: physics, physics-engine

Why do we need two constraints to calculate friction force?
$$
\begin{align}
K_{fric_1} &= J_{fric_1}M^{-1}J^T_{fric_1}  \\
 &=(-u^T_1 -(r_1 \times u_1)^T u^T_1 )(r_2 \times u_1)^T) \\
K_{fric_2} &= J_{fric_2}M^{-1}J^T_{fric_2}  \\
 &=(-u^T_2 -(r_1 \times u_2)^T u^T_2 )(r_2 \times u_2)^T)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as it's currently written, it would be a better fit on [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Consider that most game developers have not been looking at these equations as freshly as you have — most of us only touch this math on the rare instances where we're implementing a new physics engine or debugging one. The rest of the time, they're out of sight and out of mind as the physics engine does its work. So if you want a game developer's answer to this, it would help to edit your question to include a bit more background on these formulas, where you found/derived them, and what each symbol represents in that context.